# Попиксельный вывод изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Необходимо попиксельно вывести через PyQt на экран bmp-изображение, т.е. создается пустое окно, которое на глазах пользователя начинает заполняться пикселями изображения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня алгоритм в [первом ответе](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e11c7137bc88a384f384eccf910415403da625af/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt_pixel_draw_image/main.py) вызывал беспокойство, такое чувство незаконченности, ограниченности и я не выдержал и [сделал доработку](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e11c7137bc88a384f384eccf910415403da625af/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt_pixel_draw_image/main_with_fast_draw.py), которая усложнила идею первого варианта и сделала не наглядным (поэтому и решил создать новый ответ), но в то же время сделала его эффективнее.

---

Суть проста: за каждый шаг нужно обрабатывать сразу по пачке пикселей, а не по одному. Тогда на больших картинках рисование будет намного быстрее. Можно даже вывести коэффициент, который будет строиться на количестве координат в картинке, по которому за один тик таймера будут рисоваться пиксели:

```
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


IMG_FILE_NAME = 'img.png'


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('qt_pixel_draw_image')

        self.img = QImage(IMG_FILE_NAME)
        width = self.img.size().width()
        height = self.img.size().height()
        self.img = self.img.scaled(width * 3, height * 3)
        self.img_width = self.img.size().width()
        self.img_height = self.img.size().height()

        # Размер окна под размер картинок
        self.resize(self.img_width * 2 + 20, self.img_height + 20)

        # Сгенерируем список координат пикселей
        self.pixel_list = [(y, x) for y in range(self.img_height) for x in range(self.img_width)]

        # Перемешаем элементы списка случайным образом
        random.shuffle(self.pixel_list)

        self.new_img = QImage(self.img_width, self.img_height, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.new_img.fill(Qt.white)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._draw_pixel)
        self.timer.start(1)  # 1 ms

    def _draw_pixel(self):
        # Количество пикселей за один шаг
        pixels_by_step = 15

        for _ in range(pixels_by_step):
            # Если список не пустой
            if self.pixel_list:
                y, x = self.pixel_list.pop()
                pixel = self.img.pixel(x, y)

                # Установка пикселя в новой картинке
                self.new_img.setPixel(x, y, pixel)

            else:
                self.timer.stop()
                break

        # Перерисование виджета
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Рисуем старую картинку
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.img)

        # Рисуем новую картинку
        painter.drawImage(0 + self.img.width() + 10, 0, self.new_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    # w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

На старом алгоритме такая картинка рисовалась бы неприлично долго (все-таки по одному пикселю быстро не нарисовать), а если по пачке разом, то выйдет шустро:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это прямо то, то нужно!

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ правильным, чтобы не висел вопрос без ответа

Comment: Да, пардоньте, забыл на радостях!

Answer (score 4):

Привожу пример попиксельного рисования картинки ([в файле проекта можно найти больше интересного кода](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/e11c7137bc88a384f384eccf910415403da625af/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt_pixel_draw_image)):

```
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


IMG_FILE_NAME = 'img.png'


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('qt_pixel_draw_image')

        self.img = QImage(IMG_FILE_NAME)
        self.img_width = self.img.size().width()
        self.img_height = self.img.size().height()

        # Сгенерируем список координат пикселей
        self.pixel_list = [(y, x) for y in range(self.img_height) for x in range(self.img_width)]

        # Перемешаем элементы списка случайным образом
        random.shuffle(self.pixel_list)

        self.new_img = QImage(self.img_width, self.img_height, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.new_img.fill(Qt.white)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._draw_pixel)
        self.timer.start(1)  # 1 ms

    def _draw_pixel(self):
        # Если список пустой
        if not self.pixel_list:
            self.timer.stop()
            return

        y, x = self.pixel_list.pop()
        pixel = self.img.pixel(x, y)

        # Установка пикселя в новой картинке
        self.new_img.setPixel(x, y, pixel)

        # Перерисование виджета
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Рисуем старую картинку
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.img)

        # Рисуем новую картинку
        painter.drawImage(0 + self.img.width() + 10, 0, self.new_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншоты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Формат картинки тут не особо важен – Qt поддерживает разные типы, включая png, jpg, bmp, tiff, и т.п.

Для рисования использовал событие [paintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) виджета, [таймер](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), и вызов метода перерисовки [update](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update).

Для работы с картинками и их пикселями использовал [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html), т.к. в `QImage`, в отличии от [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) есть методы работы с пикселями.